# How to stop BackgroundWorker whose `DoWork` handler only contains one (long-running) statement?

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker, cancellation

I have a problem with a `BackgroundWorker` whose `DoWork` handler contains only one statement. Which means that I cannot check the `CancellationPending` flag:

```
private void BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    CallTimeConsumerFunction();
}
```

How can I stop this `BackgroundWorker`? Is there any work-around?

Comment: you should inject cancellation logic in to `CallTimeConsumerFunction()`

Answer (score 4):

Looking at .NET 4's Task Parallel Library (TPL), which came after `BackgroundWorker` and is rather well-designed, can give you an idea how you should approach this.

[Cancellation in the TPL is built on the idea of **cooperative cancellation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364(v=vs.110).aspx). This means that tasks are not forcibly stopped from the outside; instead they participate in the cancellation process by periodically checking whether cancellation has been requested and, if so, by gracefully aborting "from the inside".

I recommend you follow the TPL's example and implement cooperative cancellation. Like [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3970411/dotctor) states, inject cancellation logic into `CallTimeConsumerFunction`. For example:

```
void CallTimeConsumerFunction(Func<bool> shouldCancel)
{                          // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                           // add this; can be called to find out whether to abort or not
    … // possibly lengthy operation
    if (shouldCancel()) return;
    … // possibly lengthy operation
}

private void BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    CallTimeConsumerFunction(shouldCancel: () => backgroundWorker.CancellationPending);
}                         // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```